# How to install two versions of python in windows 10?

Tags: python, 64-bit, python-idle, 32-bit

I have installed two versions of python in my computer (python 3.7.4 and 3.9.6). But I can't open one of the version's IDLE. For example if I installed Python 3.7.4 after that 3.9.6 the IDLE of 3.9.6 is not opening and pip(p) also not working. If I tried to open the IDLE through cmd it shows
that "** IDLE can't import Tkinter. Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **" .Here I am using python 3.7.4 for 32 bit projects and python 3.9.6 for 64 bit projects. How to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your environment variables

Comment: Check this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip

Comment: You run IDLE with specific versions of IDLE either by clicking icons linked to specific python-IDLE combinations (on the start menu or added to desktop or pinned to taskbar) or by entering `py -3.x -m idlelib` commands in Command Prompt or Powershell.  `py -3.x -m pip ...` runs `pip` with 3.x.

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy yes i have tried like this only.... Python 3.7.4 is working but python 3.9.6 shows error that ** IDLE can't import Tkinter. Your Python may not be configured for Tk. ** like that... But i have checked Tcl/tk check box during installation.

Comment: Start 3.9 interactively with `py -3.9` or the 3.9 start menu icon.  Enter `import tkinter`.  What happens?

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy It shows No module named tkinter. I tried to install through pip but pip also not working. But python 3.7.4 is working fine

Comment: On Windows, installing tkinter and IDLE is a choice one makes when installing python with the python.org installer.  Installing them is the default, but you might have inadvertently clicked it off.  Re-run the 3.9.6 installer, check (X) Install tkinter and IDLE, if you can, and then whatever to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple virtual env in your system and activate specific according to your need

```
python3.7.4 -m venv python37-env
python3.9.6 -m venv python39-env
```

Refer to these document to learn more

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
```